# If condition with variables not working, but working with the actual values of the same variables

Tags: python, variables

I have a class with multiple instances, I pass these class instance as parameter to a function which calls the instance attributes and performs an if condition. Here the if condition is not performing with variables in place and neither is it throwing an error. But it works fine when I pass in actual values.

core.py

```
import execution as ex

class Everything():
    all = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.margin = 0
        self.profit_amount = 0
        self.target = 0

users = [{margin: 28000, profit_amount: 0, target:0.03}, {margin: 30000, profit_amount: 0, target:0.03}]

for x in users:
    Everything(x)

for y in Everything.all:
    ex.test(y)
```

execution.py

```
def test(ins):
    print(f'printing the values separately, margin = {ins.margin}, 
    profit amount = {ins.profit_amount}, 
    target = {ins.target}')
    if (ins.profit_amount/ins.margin) < ins.target:
        print("Steps further")
```

Here when I run core.py, the program runs till the 'printing the values separately' statement within execution file, but won't proceed any further.

Comment: Please update your question with your real code. Reading what you have posted, I imagine there would be an error here: `Everything(x)`.

Comment: The part which you are highlighting is a shortform version of instantiating from csv file actually, which is working fine actually. as said in my question, my program runs till this line

print(f'printing the values separately...


It stops only after this.

Comment: Well, there's the rub. What program are you talking about? (Please note that jonrsharpe made a mistake editing your question). I can't see anything here which will lead me to even try your code.